# Neo4j Cypher alternative for apoc.coll.union and apoc.coll.unionAll

Tags: neo4j, cypher, apoc

In order to substitute

```
apoc.coll.unionAll(list1, list2) as list3
```

looks like I may use `+` sign in pure Cypher:

```
WITH [1,2] as list1, [1,2,3,4] as list2 WITH list1 + list2 as list3
```

but how to implement `apoc.coll.union` in plain Cypher which returns a distinct union of the 2 lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwind the combined list then collect the distinct elements as union list.

```
WITH [1,2] as list1, [1,2,3,4] as list2 
UNWIND list1 + list2 as l 
RETURN collect(distinct l) as union_list
```

Result:

```
╒════════════╕
│"union_list"│
╞════════════╡
│[1,2,3,4]   │
└────────────┘
```